# How to solve the following system of linear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{dt}&=a\cdot(v-u), \\ \frac{dv}{dt}&=a\cdot(u-v)+b\cdot(w-v), \\ \frac{dw}{dt}&=b\cdot(v-w)
\end{align*}
With a and b parametres (and some initial values for u, v and w). How do I go about solving it?

I have tried adding some equations together to remove some variables/get a more useful equation: multiplying the first one by b/a and subtracting it from the third gives:

\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{dt}&=a\cdot(v-u), \\ \frac{dv}{dt}&=a\cdot(u-v)+b\cdot(w-v), \\ \frac{dw}{dt}-\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{du}{dt}&=-b\cdot w+b\cdot  u
\end{align*}

I also tried rewriting the second one to get

\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{dt}&=a\cdot(v-u), \\ \frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{du}{dt}+\frac{dw}{dt}&=0, \\ \frac{dw}{dt}-\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{du}{dt}&=-b\cdot w+b\cdot  u
\end{align*}

However I don't know what to do now. I suppose I should try to obtain an equation after which I can write a function where both u and v appear for example. I don't know how to do that though since by adding equations I just walk in circles.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also please see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3Ag8WF5M_c

Comment: HINT : add the three equations.

Comment: @JJacquelin I already did but I don't see how that helps later on

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Could you elaborate? I just have du/dt = -ax now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience let $x_1=u,x_2=v,x_3=w$. This is a linear system of first order ODEs, and can be written in matrix form:
$$\dot{\mathrm x}=\mathbf{M}\mathrm x$$
Where
$$\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}
-a & a & 0\\
a & -a-b & b\\
0 & b & -b
\end{bmatrix}$$
Such equations have a well known solution:
$$\mathrm{x}(t)=c_1\mathrm{u}_1e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2\mathrm{u}_2e^{\lambda_2t}+c_3\mathrm{u}_3e^{\lambda_3t}$$
Where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are arbitrary constants that will depend on your initial conditions, $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $\mathbf M$ and $\mathrm{u}_i$ is the corresponding eigenvector. If the eigenvalues are repeated one can make use of the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Comment: Is there a general formula to obtain these eigenvalues, so I can just write the general solution in function of a and b (or other constants)?

Comment: @DaddyMike You solve the cubic polynomial $\det(\mathbf M -\lambda \mathbf{I})=0$ for $\lambda$. There is a cubic formula but it's very unwieldy.